# Why my PickerView does not show data

Tags: ios, objective-c

My picker View is supposed to show A list of name from the array, but there is nothing showed in my testing.
But the button works fine

my .h controller is

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDSingleComponentPickerViewController : UIViewController
    <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIPickerView *singlePicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *pickerData;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

my .m controller

```
//
//  BIDSingleComponentPickerViewController.m
//  TabView
//
//  Created by y on 14-3-8.
//  Copyright (c) 2014年 Ruolin. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BIDSingleComponentPickerViewController.h"

@interface BIDSingleComponentPickerViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDSingleComponentPickerViewController

@synthesize singlePicker;
@synthesize pickerData;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Luke", @"Leia", @"Han", @"Chewbacca", @"Artoo", @"Threepio", @"Lando", nil];
    self.pickerData = array;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    self.singlePicker = nil;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger row = [singlePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSString *selected = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your selection is %@",selected];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"Thank you for choosing" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thank you" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData count];
}

#pragma mark Picker Delegate Methods
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
}


@end
```

My picker View is supposed to show A list of name from the array, but there is nothing showed in my testing.
But the button works fine

Comment: You will assign a datasource for your picker. singlePicker.delegate = self and singlePicker.datasource = self.. probably in viewDidLoad

Comment: @GenieWanted: You mean `DataSource`, since it doesn't show anything? Not about a `reaction` from user intercation.

Comment: Yes, edited the comment.. "Delegate" is something that comes to mind often.. :D

Comment: In my IOS5 development tutorial book, it seems that there is no single.delegate = self. Is this a new chang ein IOS7? Or it is an error in my book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your picker view delegate I guess you are not doing this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Luke", @"Leia", @"Han", @"Chewbacca", @"Artoo", @"Threepio", @"Lando", nil];

    self.singlePicker.delegate = self;
    self.singlePicker.dataSource = self;

    self.pickerData = array;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

The interface builder way:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I solved by following your code! I am following a IOS5 developing tutorial which does not include this singlePicker.delegate = self. Is that a new change in IOS7?

Comment: Definitely not new in iOS7. Are you sure your tutorial doesn't just set them through IB?

Comment: will do! There is a frozen time before I add it to accepted